# App linking is not working as expected in Android

Tags: android, deep-linking, android-app-links

We want an app link for our application.

We have set intent-filter in manifest as below:

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <data
        android:host="www.we.cards"
        android:pathPrefix="/wecards/"
        android:scheme="https" />

    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

</intent-filter>
```

There is a code to handle intent in the relevant activity.
It is verified too in android studio app link assistant as below:

[image]

It maps to correct activity as below:

[image]

The activity has also code to handle the intent.

However, on click of URL, instead of the direct app open - we are getting a dialog to select an option in which we are getting our app listed.

**We are expecting direct app redirection and no such dialog.**

[image]

If you have any solution, please try to elaborate as well if possible.

Answer (score 0):

App linking is working as expected because of `android:scheme="https"` used in all browser apps and you see them all in provided apps list. To achieve redirection as you expecting you have to use unique scheme, like `android:scheme="cards"` so link should looks like `cards://www.we.cards/wecards/` But if this case is unacceptable you can use [Firebase Dynamic Link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links). This is a powerfull tool with redirection to app or play market